# Extending angular-in-memory-web-api

Tags: angular, angular-in-memory-web-api

My org returns the same object for any api.

This is a wrapper around the actual normal response you would expect from a restful api 
e.g. 
api/products returns MyOrgResponse object which might look like

```
{true, products[], notifications[] }
```

and api/products/123 returns

```
{true, product123, notifications[] }
```

This breaks the angular-in-memory-web-api as it expects a restful collection to access eg.

```
{products} or {product123}
```

I can extend the service and intercept the get(reqInfo: RequestInfo) {} method. Here I can repoint to the collection its looking for (if my api/products/123 was invoked for example). I then reconstruct the body to return a MyOrgObject.

The first bit works but any ideas on how I rebuild the body/response object as my subscription is blowing up saying

```
"TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable" ...
```

I am doing this to reconstruct

```
 body:  {"operationSucceeded": true, "data": product, "notifications": []}
```

thanks

Comment: Add a method `responseInterceptor(res: ResponseOptions, ri: RequestInfo): ResponseOptions {}` in api-mock-service, do your restructuring here

Comment: I am sorry, I don't fully understand your question. `api/products/123` is a url for `in-memory` right? What is returning this type of data: `{true, product123, notifications[] } `